# Hand tracking Kinect SDK 1.7

Tags: c#, sdk, kinect

I want to detect hand state if it gripped or released using Kinect SDK v1.7 implemented with C#, but I'm tired from this an exception:

> Exception thrown: 'System.InvalidOperationException' in
>   Microsoft.Kinect.Toolkit.Interaction.dll

The code:

```cs
private void InteractionStreamOnInteractionFrameReady(object sender,InteractionFrameReadyEventArgs e)
{
using (InteractionFrame frame = e.OpenInteractionFrame())
{
 if (frame != null)
  {
   if (this.userInfos == null)
   {
     this.userInfos = new  UserInfo[InteractionFrame.UserInfoArrayLength];
   }
  frame.CopyInteractionDataTo(this.userInfos);
  }
else
 { return;}

}
foreach (UserInfo userInfo in this.userInfos)
 {
   foreach (InteractionHandPointer handPointer in  userInfo.HandPointers)
   {
     string action = null;
     switch (handPointer.HandEventType)
     {
       case InteractionHandEventType.Grip:
         action = "gripped";
         break;
       case InteractionHandEventType.GripRelease:
         action = "released";
         break;
     }
     if (action != null)
      {
       string handSide = "unknown";

       switch (handPointer.HandType)
        {
          case InteractionHandType.Left:
            handSide = "left";
            break;
          case InteractionHandType.Right:
            handSide = "right";
            break;
         }
       if (handSide == "left")
        {
          if (action == "released")
           {
            // left hand released code here
            //MessageBox.Show("left hand released");
            System.Console.WriteLine("left hand released");
            }
          else
           {
            // left hand gripped code here
            System.Console.WriteLine("left hand gripped");
           }
        }
       else
        {
         if (action == "released")
           {
           // right hand released code here
            System.Console.WriteLine("right hand released");
           }
         else
           {
            // right hand gripped code here
            System.Console.WriteLine("right hand gripped");
           }
        }
      }
   }
} 
}

 private void WindowLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
  {
   // Create the drawing group we'll use for drawing
    this.drawingGroup = new DrawingGroup();
   // Create an image source that we can use in our image control
    this.imageSource = new DrawingImage(this.drawingGroup);
   // Display the drawing using our image control
    Image.Source = this.imageSource;
    sensor = KinectSensor.KinectSensors.FirstOrDefault();
    if (null != this.sensor )
     {
       System.Console.WriteLine("Start streaming");
       skeletons = new   
       Skeleton[sensor.SkeletonStream.FrameSkeletonArrayLength];
       userInfos = new  
       UserInfo[InteractionFrame.UserInfoArrayLength];             
       this.sensor.SkeletonStream.Enable();
       this.interactionStream = new InteractionStream(this.sensor,  
       new   
       DummyInteractionClient());
       this.interactionStream.InteractionFrameReady +=  
       InteractionStreamOnInteractionFrameReady;
       sensor.SkeletonFrameReady += SensorSkeletonFrameReady;
     // Start the sensor !
       try
        {
          this.sensor.Start();
        }
       catch (IOException)
        {
          //////// this.sensor = null;
        }
   }
   if (null == this.sensor)
    {
      System.Console.WriteLine("NoKinectReady");
    }
}
```

Comment: A minimum of indentation cleanliness is vital for overview and code review, regardless of the particular issue.

Comment: @dakab thanks for your advice I've modified it :))